# Can't reopen temporary table

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

When I call the MySQL function: 'modulo_usuario_verificar_usuario_subset_usuario' as

```
SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE modulo_usuario_verificar_usuario_subset_usuario(3, id);
```

MySQL complains:

```
ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 'temp_modulo_usuario_obter_organizacoes_usuario'
```

The 'modulo_usuario_verificar_usuario_subset_usuario' function is something like this:

```
FUNCTION `modulo_usuario_verificar_usuario_subset_usuario`( in_super_usuario int unsigned, in_sub_usuario int unsigned)
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
.....some code here ....

//This SP drops, creates, and populates the temporary table:temp_modulo_usuario_obter_organizacoes_usuario
call modulo_usuario_obter_organizacoes_usuario_c(in_super_usuario);

//Using the temporary table previously created
return (select not exists ( select *
                    from sub_set 
                    where sub_set.org_id not in (   select super_set.org_id
                                                    from temp_modulo_usuario_obter_organizacoes_usuario as super_set)) as super_usuario);

END
```

Where exactly Am I reusing temporary tables? I understand that inside the function it is used once and in the select clause that calls the function the function creates a new temporary table

EDIT: I just found a good answer on why I'm not able to do so:

[Calling a procedure inside a function throws MySQL ERROR 1422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096621/calling-a-procedure-inside-a-function-throws-mysql-error-1422)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reuse temporary tables:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: You can, however, reuse a CTE "table" (8.0 / 10.2).  Before that, make a "permanent" table.  (This is sloppy, especially if multiple connections are trying to make the same temp-perm table.)

Answer (score 1):

You are in a Stored Function.  It could be that you use the tmp table in the query that is calling the function.  Or that `CALL` statement you have.  Or in some other Function call.